# cannot add class to li element for WordPress nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've found some solutions to add classes to li element, but unfortunately it's not working. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

EDITED: I also added second menu, that i'a using on page

**function.php**

```
function main_menu() {
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __('Primary Main Menu'),
    ));
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'secondary' => __('Primary Portfolio Navigation'),
    ));
}


//Remove ul wrapper from menu
function remove_ul ( $menu ){
    return preg_replace( array( '#^<ul[^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#' ), '', $menu );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'remove_ul' );


function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}

function menu_item_class( $classes, $item, $args) {
    unset($classes);
  $classes[] = "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter";
  return $classes;
}


//Menu
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'main_menu');
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'menu_item_class', 1, 3);
```

**index.php**

```
<ul>
    $args = array(
        'container' => false,
        'menu_id' => false,
        'items-wrap' => '',
        'theme_location' => 'secondary'
    );
        wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove all the classes that Wordpress adds and _only_ add your own?

Comment: add my own, right now i don't have any default classes on li elements

Comment: I was able to verify on another WordPress site that your code works just fine (both the way you have it originally and as an array like in my answer below).  Perhaps you have a caching plugin?

Comment: i don't have any caching plugin, i cleared cache by pressing CTR+F5, maybe some other code is blocking, i will post the second initialized menu.

Comment: added some more code

Comment: Try hooking your filter with a late priority instead of early. Change the third parameter to `20` instead of `1`.  I wonder if what you've done is getting overridden by another filter.

Comment: awesome thanks it worked, but one issue it applied same class to other menu, how can i specify for which menu this class should be added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150994/discussion-between-jakeparis-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you return from the nav_menu_css_class should be an array. You are *technically* returning an array with a single string, but it would be more correct to do it with each class as one element in the array:

```
function menu_item_class( $classes, $item, $args) {
    unset($classes);
  $classes = ["col-xs-6","col-sm-6","col-md-2","filter"];
  return $classes;
}
```

I wonder if that would solve your problem.

Comment: still class didn't applied, i tried even to make single class name, but not working